# What is the difference between python -V and py -V?

Tags: python, anaconda, version

I want to get the current python that I am using!

My output currently is:

```sh
python -V
Python 3.7.3

py -V
Python 3.6.8
```

What is the difference between these two commands? I have anaconda and Python installed (Python 3.7 with anaconda). I think this could be a reason but I don't know why.

which python displays:

```
which python
/c/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python

which py
/c/windows/py
```

Comment: try `which python` and `which py`

Comment: Did this.

```which python
/c/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python```
```which py
/c/windows/py```

Comment: @Adrian if you want to show us what you did and it spans over multiple lines, maybe just edit the original question instead.

Comment: Okay judging by the output the `python` command starts the interpreter you installed with anaconda, while the `py` command seems to be the interpreter that comes with windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two commands point to two different Python interpreters on your system. You can run `which py` or `which python` to see where they are located, if you are interested.

Managing different python versions in one system without the use of virtual environments *can* lead to headaches, for example when you install a package for the wrong interpreter. I would definitely recommend looking into `virtualenv` and/or `virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: I uninstalled Anaconda with all dependencies and now this problem does not occur anymore.